# Intermittent Error on truffle test - Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:

Tags: ethereum, truffle, drone.io, ganache, consensys-truffle

I have a CI pipeline on drone - This is how it executes

```
     - 'cd project'
      - 'npm install -g truffle'
      - 'npm i -g  ganache@7.0.1'
      - 'ganache -p 9546'
      - 'echo "---> Installing local packages..."'
      - 'npm install'
      - 'echo "---> Running tests..."'
      - 'truffle test'
      - 'echo "---> Truffle tests execution completed!"'
```

The issue is the pipeline fails with the following error -

[image: Error in CI pipeline]

The test cases are working fine locally on the ganache instance, but fail to execute intermittently on the CI pipeline.

The test cases pass sometimes without any issue but throw PollingBlock tracker error mostly.

I have already tried suggestions available on the internet, but the issue is still the same.
This is what my development network config looks like in truffle-config.js -

```
 development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 9546,
      network_id: "*",
      networkCheckTimeout: 1000000,
      timeoutBlocks: 50000,
      websocket: true,
      gas: 5000000,
      gasPrice: 45000000000,
      skipDryRun: false
    },
```